# Mac mini Late 2014

Tags: upgrade, memory, mac-mini

Has anyone tried upgrading the soldered RAM on the Late 2014 Mac mini?

My boss bought me this Mac as a development machine, with 4GiB RAM, and it's really just not cutting it.

The hard drive is fine, I can live with 500GB, as I upload most of my stuff to our Git servers, and it's all fine; the RAM, however, is a real bottleneck. I can't keep my applications open to debug them correctly: with my browser, IDE(s), file editors, and application open, my Mac is usually running up in the 3,7-3,8GiB RAM section, which slows this thing down tremendously.

At home, I have the same Mac, however, I don't develop at home. At all. My Mac at home works just fine, for watching films, and TV, creating basic HTML sites (templates), and using MS Office.

I need a way to get more fast memory in to this Mac, otherwise I can't work properly.

Any help with this matter is much appreciated!

Comment: While not an exact dupe per se due to the different models of Mac (Mac mini vs. MacBook), the context and answers are identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you can't upgrade the memory on the Mac mini, it's soldered together. I really don't think it is easy to solder the memory and there are really high chance that you will break the machine. The best way for you right now is to tell your boss to get a better computer (8GB of RAM is fine but I recommend 16GB or more).